# Understanding the representation of a knowledge set (finit logically closed sets)

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm having difficulties understanding the representation of a knowledge set. A knowledge set (belief set) represents the belief state of an intelligent agent and is assumed to be a logically closed set of sentences. Here we consider only finite knowledge sets. I found following two representations, and I am wondering what the relationship between these two is.

**Representation 1 by [Dupin and Prade](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-03036921/document):**
We can choose a basis, such that $K = P \cup \triangle$ consisting of a set P of propositional formulas and a set $\triangle$ of defeasible rules of the form $\alpha \rightsquigarrow \beta$ where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathcal{L}$. Here, $\rightsquigarrow$ means that it is much more likely that $\beta$ is true if $\alpha$ is true.

**Representation 2 by [Katsuno and Mendelzon](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/000437029190069V):**
If we fix a way of representing any knowledge set $K$ by a propositional
formula $\psi$ such that $K = \lbrace \phi \;\; \vert \;\; \psi \vdash \phi \rbrace$,...

Is $\psi$ somewhat equivalent to the set $P$ in Representation 2? Why is it clear that such a $\psi$ always exists?

Thanks a lot in advance!